# Upgrade interrupted with Alternative CD

Tags: installation, alternate

I was upgrading from 10.10 to 11.04 via an alternate ISO. The upgrade process was interrupted due to power failure. Further attempts to log back into my user profile ended up in failure. Whenever I tried to log in, I was sent back to the login screen.

So, how do I complete the upgrade process without GUI and ensure that I can get back to my user profile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[From a chat message from destroll:](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/3174356#3174356)

Log in using the recovery mode. Then default to root prompt. Mount the alternate ISO and run the upgrade using the command `./cdromupgrade`.